# Google Maps Android API v2 - cannot obtain a release certificate fingerprint for API key

Tags: android

I have looked in other questions but could not solve the problem.

I try to obtain a release certificate fingerprint as mentioned in: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
section: Displaying the release certificate fingerprint:

Enter the following at a terminal or command prompt:
`keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name`
Replace your_keystore_name with the fully-qualified path and name of the keystore, including the .keystore extension. Replace your_alias_name with the alias that you assigned to the certificate when you created it.
I have entered:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -keystore D:\118FarmaciaTeiCertifKeystore.keystore`
 ----to see the aliases but I keep getting the error: 
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: D:\118Farmacia
TeiCertifKeystore.keystore`

Do you know why is it?

Comment: Oh, I have figured out why is that. Event though they say to include **.keystore**, my file in not named **.keystore**. I left that out and  it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you add Java to your PATH. You'll be able to access keytool anywhere. You could then try running keytool in the directory of your keystore, see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have figured out why is that. Event though they say to include .keystore, my file in not named .keystore. I left that out and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

copy your .keystore file from D: directory  to java bin folder after that try this one.may be it's working.
keytool -list -alias -keystore yourkeystorefile.keystore

Comment: Thank you very much. I have figured out why is that. Event though they say to include .keystore, my file in not named .keystore. I left that out and it worked.